# How to find which row items are appearing most in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apriori

I have a dataframe something like this :

```
    a   b   c   d   e   f
  ------------------------
0   0   0   1   1   0   1
1   1   0   1   1   0   0
2   0   0   1   1   0   1
3   1   0   1   0   0   0
4   0   0   1   1   0   1
5   0   1   1   0   0   0
6   1   0   1   0   1   1
7   0   0   1   1   0   1
8   1   0   1   1   1   0
9   0   0   1   1   0   1
```

How to find which row is appearing the most number of times and unique items count?
Here `0  0  1   1   0   1` this is appearing most times in rows `0,2,4,7,9`.

I tried `apriori algorithm` ,but it is giving me 100+ rules if my data is big.
.NB : My real data is not `0` and `1`. This is mock data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by all columns with `size` and for index by max value add [`idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.idxmax.html):

```
out = df.groupby(df.columns.tolist()).size().idxmax()
print (out)
(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1)
```

And for index values [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with compare by `max` value:

```
s = df.groupby(df.columns.tolist())[df.columns[0]].transform('size')
idx = s.index[s == s.max()]
print (idx)
Int64Index([0, 2, 4, 7, 9], dtype='int64')
```

Comment: How to display all patterns oneby one beased on the count?

Comment: It return only top one pattern,  if want use all patterns use `df = df.drop_duplicates()`

Comment: Is there anyway to count each pattern and display its count like a ranking?

Comment: Do you think `df.groupby(df.columns.tolist()).size().reset_index(name='count')` ?

Comment: What if count of two items are same? how to display both/all

Comment: @qwww - hmmm, so there are top values with same counts?

Comment: yes i had another file with similar data... it showed top values with same count. It displayed only first set of data.. but idx gives two times the count.. if top value is 10 idx will display 10*number of times

Comment: Then need modify first solution like `s = df.groupby(df.columns.tolist()).size()` and `out = s[s == s.max()]`.sort_values().reset_index()` - get all top values.